# Conjugate gradient with incomplete cholesky preconditioner returns errors for Eigen library

Tags: eigen

I'm using Eigen library to solve Ax=b, the default preconditioner didn't do well in time performance ,so I want to try some other predonditioners, such as incomplete cholesky preconditioner,here is my code:

```
Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::Lower | Eigen::Upper, Eigen::IncompleteCholesky<double> > cg;
```

I just add the incomplete cholesky preconditioner to my code. But on compilation with Visual Studio 2019 in windows10 I got the following error:

```
"twistedBy": is not the member of  "Eigen::SelfAdjointView<const Derived,1>"    D:\eigen_test\eigen\Eigen\src\IterativeLinearSolvers\IncompleteCholesky.h   202
```

(I'm using Chinese version of vs2019 so I translated the error message into English)

Comment: consider posting on scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you want help with non-working code, you need to post a [mre].